# special meaning of ramp

Tags: word-meaning, idioms

I read an article recently online that is about the effect of coronavirus pandemic. One of men said in an interview that "As restaurants come back online, we're anxious to see what that ***ramp*** is," "You know, we don't know if that ***ramp*** is going to be back to 100 percent in one month, or is it six months?"

I looked up in the dictionary for the word "ramp", and all the meanings seem not applicable in the sentence above. Does ramp have an another meaning except sloping surface or slip road?

Here's the link https://www.republicworld.com/world-news/us-news/pandemic-puts-restaurants-staff-in-limbo.html

Thank you

Comment: A ramp is an incline or slope, and the word can be used about the steepness of a line on a graph representing the amount of business done by restaurants. How steep is the line (ramp) on the graph? = How fast is the recovery?

Comment: There was obviously some preceding reference to *the speed at which the hospitality industry can [**ramp back up**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ramp-up) to normal / pre-pandemic levels*, as indicated by the backward-referencing ***that** ramp*.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

A ramp is an incline or slope, and the word is used about the steepness of a line on a graph representing the amount of business done by restaurants. How steep is the line (ramp) on the graph? = How fast is the recovery?